# How to get JSON value using Java

Tags: java, deserialization, json

I want to get a value from JSON using Java.

The value I want to get is `city` and `country`.

I use json-simple library, Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "company" : {
    "name" : {
      "leader" : "leader_name" 
    },
    "location" : {
      "city" : "city_name",
      "country" : "country_name"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Code:

```
package readjson;

import java.io.FileReader;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class ReadJson {

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
    try {

        Object object = jp.parse(new FileReader("/home/azuharu/output.json"));
        JSONObject jso = (JSONObject) object;

        String city = (String) jso.get("city");
        String country = (String) jso.get("country");

        System.out.println("city: "+city);
        System.out.println("country: "+country);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
  }
}
```

city and country is null and I expect it to be.  Why isn't the correct value being printed?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I dont know why there is no error,
the value is null,
city: null
country: null

Comment: How do you know? You never print `city` or `country`. Please include the *real* code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must navigate to `/company/location` first:

```
JSONObject jso = (JSONObject) object;
JSONObject company = (JSONObject) jso.get("company");
JSONObject location = (JSONObject) company.get("location");
String city = (String) location.get("city");
String country = (String) location.get("country");
```